# use pandas to check first digit of a column

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem**
I need to test the first digit of each number in a column for conditions.

**Conditions**
is the first digit of checkVar greater than 5
or
is the first digit of checkVar less than 2

then set newVar=1

**Solution**

One thought that I had was to convert to it a string, left strip the space, and then take [0], but i can't figure out the code.

perhaps something like,

```
df.ix[df.checkVar.str[0:1].str.contains('1'),'newVar']=1
```

It isn't what I want, and for some reason i get this error

```
invalid index to scalar variable.
```

testing my original variable i get values that should meet the condition

```
df.checkVar.value_counts()
301    62
1      15
2       5
999     3
dtype: int64
```

ideally it would look something like this:

```
            checkVar  newVar
NaN  1         nan    
     2         nan
     3         nan
     4         nan
     5       301.0
     6       301.0
     7       301.0
     8       301.0
     9       301.0
     10      301.0
     11      301.0
     12      301.0
     13      301.0
     14        1.0     1
     15        1.0     1
```

**UPDATE**
My final solution, since actual problem was more complex

```
w = df.EligibilityStatusSP3.dropna().astype(str).str[0].astype(int)
v = df.EligibilityStatusSP2.dropna().astype(str).str[0].astype(int)
u = df.EligibilityStatusSP1.dropna().astype(str).str[0].astype(int)
t = df.EligibilityStatus.dropna().astype(str).str[0].astype(int) #get a series of the first digits of non-nan numbers
df['MCelig'] = ((t < 5)|(t == 9)|(u < 5)|(v < 5)|(w < 5)).astype(int)
df.MCelig = df.MCelig.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
t = df.checkVar.dropna().astype(str).str[0].astype(int) #get a series of the first digits of non-nan numbers
df['newVar'] = ((t > 5) | (t < 2)).astype(int)
df.newVar = df.newVar.fillna(0)
```

this might be slightly better, unsure, but another, very similar way to approach it.

```
t = df.checkVar.dropna().astype(str).str[0].astype(int)
df['newVar'] = 0
df.newVar.update(((t > 5) | (t < 2)).astype(int))
```

Comment: clever solution.  I'm writing this down :-)

Comment: you got it working? which part is confusing? i'll break it apart for you.

Comment: Thank you, yes.  my problem was unrelated.  I was doing a pd.wide_to_long going into this command, and i messed up my index variable.  it works great!

Answer (score 1):

It helpful to break up the steps a bit when you are uncertain how to proceed.

```
def checkvar(x):
    s = str(x)
    first_d = int(s[0])
    if first_d < 2 or first_d > 5:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Change the "else: return" value to whatever you want (e.g., "else: pass").  Also, if you want to create a new column:

*Update - I didn't notice the NaNs before.  I see that you are still having problems even with the dropna().  Does the following work for you, like it does for me?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old_col': [None, None, None, 13, 75, 22, 51, 61, 31]})
df['new_col'] = df['old_col'].dropna().apply(checkvar)
df
```

If so Maybe the issue in your data is with the dtype of 'old_col'?  Have you tried converting it to float first?

```
df['old_col'] = df['old_col'].astype('float')
```

Comment: I believe that str() or the int() in the 1st line of your function wouldn't like a NaN.  You could change your apply to df.new_var = df.ID.dropna().apply(checker) or test for NaN in your function